# Dropping tablespaces with tables/indexes in them in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

What happens to tables allocated to a tablespace when a tablespace is removed? As in, when drop tablespace is executed? From what I observed, a tablespace in YugabyteDB is a logical construct only taking effect when a table is created or altered with a tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to drop a tablespace when other tables are using it. It's possible that this was not fixed in an older release but it should not happen in a release where the feature is production-ready.

A tablespace is not only a logical construction, it is a construction to group objects with the idea to put them in specific place. This is both true for PostgreSQL and for YugabyteDB.

Logically if you drop the parent object of children, the children are deleted. But as been stated, as long as there are objects in a tablespace, it can't be dropped.